# rails carmen country_select helper without a form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my form is not tied to a particular model and looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'orders' , :action => 'process_credit_card') do  %>
    ... bunch of fields ...
<% end %>
```

[carmen-rails](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails)' `country_select` helper looks like this

```
 <%= f.country_select :country_code, {priority: %w(US CA)}, prompt: 'Please select a country' %>
```

however I do not have a form object `f`, I use helpers like `<%= text_field_tag 'billing_address[phone]' %>` to create my form, is there a way I can still use carmen in this form?

UPDATE: I am using ActiveMerchant for payment processing, I can create a form with `form_for` instead of `form_tag` but I don't know how, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this should work...

```
<%= country_select :country_code, {priority: %w(US CA)}, prompt: 'Select' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years late, but I ran into this problem tonight and found a solution that worked for me by crawling through the carmen-rails source code. Note that the second hash (as the fourth argument) can contain HTML options like `class`.

```
<%= country_select(nil, :country_code, { priority: %w(US CA) }, {}) %>
```

With the other solutions (that did not have `nil` as the first argument) I was having serialization issues with my AJAX search functionality. The entire hash (including priority and other code) would be serialized with the request. When calling it like I have above, this is no longer an issue and only the country code is serialized. Hopefully this will help someone in the future who ran into the same issue we did.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<%= country_select(nil,:country, { priority: %w(US CA) , prompt: 'Select Country'},:class=>"form-control") %>
```

Use above with `form_tag`

```
<%= f.country_select :country, {priority: %w(US CA), prompt: 'Select Country'},:class=>"form-control" %>
```

and use above with `form_for`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this isn't by using the `country_select` gem but a dependency it has `countries` gem and plain Rails form helpers `select_tag` and `options_for_select`: [Using country_select gem with form_tag and no model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410077/using-country-select-gem-with-form-tag-and-no-model/34940945#34940945)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`<%= country_select_tag :country_code, {priority: %w(US CA)}, prompt: 'Please select a country' %>`

Comment: already did, doesn't work, carmen-rails doesn't have this method in the docs either.