# Using country_select gem with form_tag and no model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the country_select gem in Rails 4 in a form tag:

```
<%= form_tag(@url, method: :post, class: "form-horizontal") do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag(:country_code, "Country code") %>
      <%= country_select :country_code, @country_code, class: "form-control" %>
    </div><% end %>
```

I am getting the following error.

```
undefined method `NZ' for "NZ":String
```

This is a quiet unusual error and I have not found any other instances of it for the country_select gem. The rails application does not have a database and is communicating to an external database so there are no models in this application. I have been suggested to use Open Struct to get around this issue. However, I am wondering does anyone know of a quicker fix? The form is picking up the data in the database though!

Comment: It seems a gem problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the fact that I had no model. I needed to use the OpenStruct data structure which helped me to simulate objects. You can read more about it [here](http://palexander.posthaven.com/ruby-data-object-comparison-or-why-you-should-never-ever-use-openstruct)

Answer (score 4):

Since you've probably got the `country_select` gem in your app you also have the `countries` gem as it is a dependency of `country_select`. So you could just used the plain Rails form helpers `select_tag` and `options_for_select` using the `countries` gem like this:

```
select_tag :country, options_for_select(ISO3166::Country.all, params[:country])
```

Which is a much better choice than using OpenStruct to do this.

See for details and other finders you can use instead of `ISO3166::Country.all` https://github.com/hexorx/countries